# ViewPager not showing proper image when going back

Tags: java, android, image, android-viewpager

im using a `ViewPager` for showing images (in swipe mode) 1-5 images totally.
my page adapter

```
public class SimplePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SimplePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Logger.e("POSITION = "+position);
            currentBitmap = MediaHelper.bitmaps.get(position);
            return fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return IMAGE_COUNT;
        }
    }
```

Example i have 3 images. 
When i swipe from start (left to right) , my Logger show me position 0,1,2. When i swipe back (from right to left) Logger not working and "Image not updated to previsius, its keep my last image (like image on position 2 will be on all positions (0,1).
Can any help me , how to solve it ?

```
fragments its ArrayList<Fragments>
```

how its work : img1 = a, img2 = b, img3 = c;
move from a to b to c 
when going back from c to b - b have img3, move from b to a , a have img3.

**[solution]**
change fragmentAdapter to PagerAdapter

```
  class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        Context mContext;
        LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

        public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context) {
            mContext = context;
            mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return MAX_PAGES;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.image_fragment_one, container, false);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewFragment);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(MediaHelper.bitmaps.get(position));
            container.addView(itemView);
            return itemView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
        }
    }
```

Comment: try SimplePagerAdapter  extend PagerAdapter not FragmentPagerAdapter http://www.androhub.com/android-image-slider-using-viewpager/

Comment: thank for answer. PagerAdapter looks better than stupid fragments